# Advanced SQL - how can I show running sum across multiple columns in a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a need to generate a report, I did it using union but that is not the requirement.

Here is the problem statement:

The table contains sale information for items on some stores for year 2010 and 2011. I just want to display the sum of sales aggregated at item level, then store level then year level then grand total.

You can create sample data using these SQL statements:

```
create table item_sto_year_sale_t
(
     itemno integer,
     store varchar2(10),
     year integer,
     sale integer
);

insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(1,'A',2010,100);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(2,'A',2010,200);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(3,'A',2010,300);

insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(1,'B',2010,105);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(2,'B',2010,205);

insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(1,'A',2011,110);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(2,'A',2011,220);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(3,'A',2011,330);

insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(1,'B',2011,115);
insert into item_sto_year_sale_t values(2,'B',2011,225);

commit;
```

Desired output is

```
    ITEMNO STORE            YEAR        SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1                              430   ---- sum(sales) in all stores for all years where itemno = 1
         2                              850   ---- sum(sales) in all stores for all years where itemno = 2
         3                              630   ---- sum(sales) in all stores for all years where itemno = 3
           A                           1260   ---- sum(sales) for all items for all years in store = 'A'
           B                            650   ---- sum(sales) for all items for all years in store = 'A'
                            2010        910   ---- sum(sales) for all items in all stores where year = 2010
                            2011       1000   ---- sum(sales) for all items in all stores where year = 2011
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Why can't you use `union`?  I'm not sure why you would do this without 3 statements unioned together.

Comment: Oks so you say we do union and in each SQL you select 4 columns and based on sql we leave other two null ? that i can do . any other way ?

Comment: did it .. it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `GROUPING SETS` - It is pretty simple and straightforward than using multiple `UNION`

```
SELECT itemno
    ,store
    ,year
    ,SUM(SALE)
FROM item_sto_year_sale_t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((itemno), (store), (year));
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/PAEE37148)

Comment: perfect this is the function i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct to_char(itemno) , '' as STORE ,'' as YEAR,sum(sale)over(partition by itemno) as SUM from item_sto_year_sale_t
union 
select distinct '', STORE, '',sum(sale)over(partition by STORE) from item_sto_year_sale_t
union 
select distinct '', '', TO_CHAR(YEAR) ,sum(sale)over(partition by YEAR) from item_sto_year_sale_t
```